# using curl get string and find specific value from string

Tags: php, if-statement, curl

In this code, the value of `$new_el[0]` should be changed from what we get in the server response. I want the code to function such that if the value that comes from the server is  `$new_el[0]=0;` then the value of `$new_el[0]="CJ";` and if the value that comes from the server is `$new_el[0]=1;` then the value of `$new_el[0]=01;` So basically, a `0` is add before every single digit, such as 01,02,03 (except for the case of `$new_el[0] = 0`).

```
  function curlUsingGet($url, $data)
   {

if(empty($url) OR empty($data))
{
    return 'Error: invalid Url or Data';
}

$fields_string = '';
foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

$urlStringData = $url.'?'.$fields_string;
$_SESSION['urlStringData']=$urlStringData;
 $cookie= "cookie.txt";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$urlStringData);

$return = curl_exec($ch);

$arrel = explode('|',$return);

foreach($arrel as $val)
{


$new_el=explode('~',$val);


  echo $new_el[0];
  echo $new_el[1];

}

curl_close($ch);    
}

$data = array('u' =>$_SESSION['councel']);
echo curlUsingGet('http://"url":8080/causelist/CauseListData',$data);
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 0):

You can pad the number with 0's using [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf). Try something like this as a starting point.

```
$new_el[0] = ($new_el[0] == 0) ? 'CJ' : sprintf("%02d", $new_el[0]);
```